# Multiple Label or tag in PHP

Tags: php, tags, label

I am currently creating a blog in PHP and currently the blog can only accept single label or tag per post.

Please give me an idea on how to create or add multiple label or tag per post in PHP. I want the post to have multiple label or tag.

Thank you

Comment: Simple, Use a  table  for example :  ID blog_post_id  tags in this way you can keep more than one tags for one post

Comment: Flagged as too broad. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Think many-to-many relationship.  two tables joined by a link table

Comment: @jewelhuq `tag` column should be singular. Otherwise he's likely to put a comma-separated list in there.

Comment: @jewelhuq - yes I have created that

and Barmar - Yes I think comma-separated list is my first option to try on similar to blogger.

Thanks guys let me try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of database you use is very important. This would be much easier to do on something like MongoDB for example, but for the sake of cross-compatibility, here is an easy flat way to do it.

**Option 1:**
Here is a quick hack that everybody will downvote but that I am alright with.

```
<?php
    $tags = "tag1,tag2,tag3";

    $exploded_tags = explode(",", $tags);

    foreach( $exploded_tags as $elem ) {
         echo $elem;
    }
```

Store them as comma separated tags and when you query your database for the tags, explode them.

**Option 2:**

Your "blog post" must be identified somehow on the database, say by title "my-blog-post". So you'll have one table called "blog_posts" and another called "tags". Within "tags" you'll have a column called "post_title". And let's say you are passing the title of the post within your URL, you could use a get to grab that title:

```
<?php
    $post_title = $_GET['post']; // my-blog-post
    $post_tags = array("tag1","tag2","tag3");

    function insert_tags($title, $tags) {
    $query = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO `tags` (`post_title`, `tags`) VALUES(?,?)" ); // this Query inserts the post title for each tag to identify

    $query->bindValue(1, $title); // injects the title to the column post_title
    $query->bindValue(2,  $tags); // injects the tag to the column tags

    try {
    $query->execute(); // executes the above query
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    return 0; // please don't do parenthesis 
    }

    foreach( $post_tags as $elems ) {
    // since the tags are in an array, we need to loop through them
    insert_tags($post_title, $elems);
    // this function will now insert each individual tag with the title "my-blog-post"
    }
```

There's PDO in the code, so if you don't use PDO it can still be adapted to mysqli or something. Now, once you have entered in your tags you can recall it with something like this:

```
<?php
    function find_tags($post_title) {
    $query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tags` WHERE `post_title` = ?' ");

    $query->bindValue(1, $post_title);

    $query->execute(); // getting rid of exceptions for ease. This will execute the query

    return $query->fetchAll(); // Because we are fetching 2 if not more rows, we need to tell PDO to fetch everything it found and return it to the function that called it

    }

    $tags = find_tags($_GET['post_title']); //my-post-title

    foreach( $tags as $elems ) { 
    echo $elems;
    }
```

This, for the most part, should work. Foreachs may be a bit overkill but that's the general idea. Let me know if you need explanation

Comment: Thank you so so much for this options you provided I will surely try this and get back once I get the result. Thank you again

Comment: It worked! It worked! It worked! It worked! It worked! It worked! It worked!

The Option 1 did all the trick! :D

Thank you so so much for the code, I was able to add links on each tag as well. Thanks a lot, case closed. :)